# @s not working in /execute command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

(Minecraft Version 1.19.2)
I want to make emerald block particles appear whenever someone is holding a stick with the tag weap1.

```
/execute if entity @a[nbt={SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:stick",Count:1b,tag:{weap1:1b}}}] run execute at @s run particle block emerald_block ~ ~ ~ 0.5 1.5 0.5 0.3 1 normal
```

However, the @s in the second /execute command did not work at all. It was supposed to trace back to the player who's currently holding the stick and give out the particles at their own position.

Is there any other way around or was my command mistaken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` will check if at least one of the entities with those specifications exist, not execute from/as them. You are probably looking for:

```
/execute as @a if @s[...] run ...
```

Or even straight up just the `as` statement

```
/execute as @a[...] run ...
```

And then the `@s` after the run command should target what you want.